# Added new property to ViewBag. Works when ran from Visual Studio, but live version throws Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, nullreferenceexception, viewbag

I have an intranet site where I've added a new property to the ViewBag. When I run in IIS Express via Visual Studio, my changes work fine, but when I updated the actual website (in test) it throws "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

So I know the ViewBag property that I'm referencing must be null at that point, but I don't see how. I am initializing it in the controller. Here's where the error is being thrown:

```
@if (ViewBag.FRCP.Count > 0)
```

Here is where I'm setting the value in the controller:

```
//Fatal Risk Control Protocols
            List<Documents> FRCPLst = (from x in db.Documents
                                    where x.DocumentTypeId == 29
                                    orderby x.DocumentTitle
                                    select x).ToList();
            ViewBag.FRCP = FRCPLst;
```

This is in the `ActionResult Index()` method in the `HomeController` class, which is an extension of the `BaseController` class.

I inherited this intranet site from the person that was previously in my role, and I'm very new to MVC so please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: If your works on IISExpress, then problem seems not in code, but deployment. How exactly did you updated your intranet website? Did you manually copied all your views and dll files to server? Maybe you forgot some file?

Comment: I suspect you are right. The only files showing changed in the changes tab on team explorer are the few changes I made but it must be something that the change auto-detect for VS doesn't pick up. I'll do a more thorough once over and update the question if you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer comes courtesy of Arturs Mednis. This was a deployment issue. I missed one or more files when deploying my code.